# how to redirect my express app to different ports based on the incoming request

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I have implemented dynamic routing in my express app and I want to send each client request on a different port while my main  app is running on a different port.

Right now my app.js looks something like this:

```
app.use('/:client/',middleware);
```

middleware:

```
var router  = require('express').Router({mergeParams: true});
router.get('/api/:module/:controller/:action',(req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.params);
var controller = "./server/leg/fe/clients/"+req.params.client+"/main/process/"+req.params.module+"/controllers/"+req.params.controller;
var controller_class = require(controller);
console.log(controller);
var controllerObj = new controller_class();
console.log(controllerObj);
var action = req.params.action;
res.send(controllerObj[action]());
});
module.exports = router;
```

Now I would like to redirect each client to a different port based on `req.params.client` value while my app.js runs on 3000 throughout. I did look this up but they create different instances of express to achieve this which is not what I want to do. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Edit:
I have tried using http.createServer by modifying my middleware something like:

```
router.get('/api/:module/:controller/:action',(req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.params);
var controller = "./fe-server/legislations/fe/clients/"+req.params.client+"/main/process/"+req.params.module+"/controllers/"+req.params.controller;
var controller_class = require(controller);
console.log(controller);
var controllerObj = new controller_class();
console.log(controllerObj);
var action = req.params.action;
console.log(req.body.url);
var url = req.body.url;
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: url.protocol
}, res.send(controllerObj[action]()));
}).listen(8000);
});
```

but here a lot of things confuse, I can't figure out target url and not sure where `res.send` will go.

Comment: Individual ports for individual customers?. Sounds weird!.. Perhaps you should look for some other solution approach. Opening up ports would invite hackers to pitch in.

Comment: @DavidR the thing is, I want to use `client` name throughout my application so that require statements from different levels of inheritance can use that to resolve path. Setting `req.params.client` as global doesn't help as it will be overwritten if another request hits in between. Session also uses req so it needs access to req as well. http-context couldn't do it either. This seems like the only possible solution